# Baseline method for handling popularity bias in recommender system

Tags: recommender-system

I am building a recommender system of ads based on a feedforward neural network, where I rank ads by their probability of receiving certain user feedback (e.g. clcik, install, etc). To do so, I use context and user features (time, country, etc), as well as the embedding vector of the ad being ranked. The model target is binary, considering the presence of the user feedback as the positive class. Thus, at serving time my model computes the probability of receiving a feedback for a set of candidate ads. As a reference, I am following a similar approach to the ranking strategy described in [this paper.](https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/45530.pdf)

1. I would like to know how to handle ads that are very popular (i.e. are very likely to receive a feedback event) in this setting at training and serving time. Such ads would dominate recommendations.
2. Should I care about that?